# Bootstrap's dropdowns close in less than a sec after pressing them (Android 4.2.1, stock browser)

Tags: javascript, android, html, twitter-bootstrap

There's a problem with Twitter Bootstrap's dropdown menus on mobile. If I use Android's stock browser and click on a menu, it will open and close in less than a sec without me doing anything else. The same thing happens if I press the dropdowns on the official Bootstrap site, so this has nothing to do with my code.

If you want to keep the dropdowns open and fix this, you have to tap them for a little bit longer, smth like 1 second. But obviously I'd like a simple tap to be enough.

Is this normal for Android's stock browser? In Firefox and Opera Mini dropdowns work just fine.

Thanks!

PS: no, I don't have any form inside dropdowns. Only links that work fine in other browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an android browser thing. They handle links with dropdowns as both a hover and click. Other browser such as iOS handles menus with dropdowns as just the hover then another click to initiate the link.